# Did not receive ping that Earth Science was in beta?

Tags: support, private-beta, committment

Signed up for the beta a few weeks ago, and at that point it seemed as if it was likely that the site would hit beta soon after; which it did.  Found out the site was in beta by return to the Area-51 page for the site just now.

Should I have gotten a ping to let me know that the site was now in beta, since it appears that I did not get one? If this is the default, seems like a pretty odd way to launch a site, though pretty sure on another beta I got an email, though don't recall getting a ping via SE's inbox or achievements alerts; which to me would make more sense than an email alert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An email should have been sent out to everyone committed to the site when private beta started. I know I got one.

As far as I know, that is the only notification you'll get when private beta begins.

Comment: Thought so, though in the case of SE, I created an email just for it and never check it, though I am on SE almost everyday.